# How to upgrade PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6 on Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)

Tags: php, debian, debian-wheezy

I've added these lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
```

But still `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade` don't touch php.

`php --version` is still

```
PHP 5.4.39-0+deb7u2 (cli) (built: Mar 25 2015 08:33:29)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(**Update**)
Try this (Ubuntu):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm -y
```

**(Update)**
For Debian Wheezy (with sudo)

```
echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list
echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O- | apt-key add - 
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-cli php5-fpm ….. (or whatever package you might need)
```

**(Update 21/06/2017)**
For Debian 8 (jessie)

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following repositories:

```
...
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then update your sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the php5-fpm

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on wheezy. Perhaps it has been removed? See http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: I updated the reference for Wheezy installation.

Comment: This is not working on `Debian 8`, Why ?

Comment: @Nullpointer I update the answer

Comment: Doesn't work for me on debian 7. It installed php 5.4 which is the one I already had.

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts all
```

save and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

more info here
https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/

Comment: interesting, when I do this I get back `php5 is already the newest version.`

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: I kept getting an error NO_PUBKEY, had to do: `gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 89DF5277`
`gpg -a --export 89DF5277 | sudo apt-key add -`  thanks to: https://www.dotdeb.org/2010/07/11/dotdeb-packages-are-now-signed/

Answer (score -1):

After you have done `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` you'll have to do a install with:

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Comment: Last version of php in the official wheezy repos is 5.4, so your solution is invalid in this context.